# bc behaves differently on Solaris and Linux

Tags: shell, solaris, bc

I have the following problem that I have not resolved for a long time now. We have a Linux (x86_64 GNU/Linux) server and a Solaris (SunOS 5.10 i86pc Solaris) server where I work. On the linux server, the command `bc -l` gives me a calculator where I can easily work with the numerals and commands, along with using the left and right arrows to navigate. Using the up/down arrows gives me the history of my commands. It's another story on Solaris though. The arrow keys do not work at all. I cannot edit the line, nor can I get the history. Can someone here please help me set up the proper configuration of `bc` on the Solaris OS?

Comment: You'll probably need `bc` compiled with `readline` support: https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_chapter/bc_7.html Solaris may have GNU bc available (I haven't used it for a long time, so I don't remember).

Comment: I am not a root user. So the only way is to download and compile my own version of bc? Could yiu suggest a link to a proper source?

Comment: I downloaded bc-1.06 and tried to compiled. With option --with-realine it is not complied, with --with-weditline it is complied but get me segmentation fault when  I am running it.

Comment: It's `--with-editline`, without a `w`, I think (and that needs a BSD library, unlikely to be present. Do you have any GNU utility installed on your system? If not, try compiling GNU readline as well.

Comment: Yes, I just made a typo here. But even so it does not work for me.;( I resolved the segmentation problem but the final compiled version with --with-editline still gets me the same problem.

Comment: The behavior of `bc` on Linux variants is heavily influenced by Bash Try setting your `SHELL` environment variable to `/bin/bash` if you haven't already. As @muru points out, `readline` controls this behavior

Comment: @eyoung100 Right now I have SHELL=/usr/gnu/bin/bash. Setting it to /bin/bash does not change anything in bc behavior (good on Linux bad on Solaris)

Comment: Welcome to the difference between Unix (Posix) and GNU. Solaris is a Unix, Linux is GNU.

Answer (score 1):

The `bc` that comes with Solaris is quite historic.

To get the same `bc` feeling as on Linux just [install](http://www.opencsw.org/manual/for-administrators/getting-started.html#getting-started) the [gbc OpenCSW package](http://www.opencsw.org/qa/package/gbc/).

Comment: OP doesn't have root access. Can this package be installed by a user locally?

Comment: I am sorry for tiresomeness but I am not so good in all these packages. When I click there I finally get the same bc source I already tried to compile.

Comment: @muru, short answer: [no](http://www.opencsw.org/community/questions/9/can-i-install-an-opencsw-package-as-a-regular-user)

Comment: It's probably not historic, but Unix.